# Getting value from list using keys

Tags: python

How do I get the value of an item in the list when requesting its "key"?

e.g. I currently have the following list:

```
[{'rev': '1', 'time': '1448300582', 'action': 'move/add', 'title': 'test.log'}, {'rev': '0', 'time': '1448300582', 'action': 'delete', 'title': 'python.py'} {'rev': '12', 'time': '1448300582', 'action': 'move/add', 'title': 'Hello.txt'}]
```

How do I cycle through to print the title and revision of each file

```
Dictionary = [{'rev': '1', 'time': '1448300582', 'action': 'move/add', 'title': 'test.log'}, ...
KeyList = ['rev', 'time', 'action', 'type', 'title']
for Key in KeyList:
    print Key, "=", Dictionary[title]
```

And I am currently getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "P:/Scripts/PerforceSearchTool.py", line 45, in <module>
    GetFiles()
  File "P:/Scripts/PerforceSearchTool.py", line 28, in GetFiles
    print Key, "=", Dictionary[depotFile]
NameError: global name 'depotFile' is not defined
```

The list in the end will contain thousands of files. I would like to be able to search the list for each of the files titles. And for the matching title return its title, depending on its action.

Comment: What have you tried? Do you have any problems? Show us the code. Your problem can be solved with a for loop and a little bit of code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a for loop:

```
mylist = [{'rev': '1', 'time': '1448300582', 'action': 'move/add', 'title': 'test.log'}, {'rev': '0', 'time': '1448300582', 'action': 'delete', 'title': 'python.py'}, {'rev': '12', 'time': '1448300582', 'action': 'move/add', 'title': 'Hello.txt'}]

for i in mylist:
    print("Title: {}, Revision: {}".format(i["title"],i["rev"]))
```

Output:

```
Title: test.log, Revision: 1
Title: python.py, Revision: 0
Title: Hello.txt, Revision: 12
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
a = [{'rev': '1', 'time': '1448300582', 'action': 'move/add', 'title':     'test.log'}, {'rev': '0', 'time': '1448300582', 'action': 'delete', 'title':  'python.py'} {'rev': '12', 'time': '1448300582', 'action': 'move/add', 'title': 'Hello.txt'}]

for x in range(len(a)):
    print a[x]['title']
    print a[x]['rev']
```

Greetings

Answer (score 1):

To print title and revision of each element you can do something like this:

```
a =  [{'rev': '1', 'time': '1448300582', 'action': 'move/add', 'title': 'test.log'}, {'rev': '0', 'time': '1448300582', 'action': 'delete', 'title': 'python.py'}, {'rev': '12', 'time': '1448300582', 'action': 'move/add', 'title': 'Hello.txt'}]
for e in a:
  print e['title'] + ' ' + e['rev']
```

It outputs this data:

```
test.log 1
python.py 0
Hello.txt 12
```